# Is javax.naming.InitialContext ThreadSafe

Tags: java, thread-safety, jndi

Currently I am use following code to lookup EJB3 sateless session beans for normal POJO class. (We are in JEE5 so we can not inject Stateless Session Beans in normal POJO class I have to use look up)

```
import javax.naming.Context;  
import javax.naming.InitialContext;  
import javax.naming.NamingException;  

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;  

public Object getEJB(String jndiName) {  

                logger.debug("WEBSPHERE EJB Lookup : " + jndiName);  
                String modifiedJndiName = "";  
                Hashtable<Object, Object> properties = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();  
                properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");  
                properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2809");  
                try {  
                    Context context = new InitialContext(properties);  
                    logger.debug("WEBSPHERE EJB Lookup Modified JNDI Name: " + modifiedJndiName);  
                    return context.lookup("ejblocal:"+modifiedJndiName);  
                }catch (NamingException ne) {  
                    logger.debug("Naming Exception occurred :"+jndiName +">>>"+ne.getMessage());  
                    logger.error(ne.getMessage(), ne);  
                }  

                return null;  
            }
```

So is Context object is ThredSafe? should I create Context object for each call [as shown in this code snippet] or I can reuse the Context for all threads?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/faq.html#1

Answer (score 15):

Answers with regard to threadsafety are usually already mentioned in javadoc, whenever relevant. And indeed, the [`InitialContext` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html) mentions the following:

> An `InitialContext` instance is not synchronized against concurrent access by multiple threads. Multiple threads each manipulating a different `InitialContext` instance need not synchronize. Threads that need to access a single `InitialContext` instance concurrently should synchronize amongst themselves and provide the necessary locking.

The last sentence confirms it: it's not threadsafe and per-thread synchronization is necessary. In *your particular* code example, however, no synchronization is necessary as it's been created in method local scope anyway (i.e. it's definitely not shared among threads). If the `InitialContext` was in your particular code example been an instance variable, then you'd have to add the `synchronized` keyword to the `getEJB()` method.

Comment: Is it required to make synchronizing when *querying* (and not manipulating it) a single InitialContext?

Comment: IMO, yes. I got NPEx when getting the single context in different threads.

Comment: @Amir: it's mentioned in last sentence of the javadoc, as pointed out in my answer.

Comment: InitialContext is not thread-safe, I now know from experience :). If multiple threads access it, you are bound to have runtime-exceptions. I have a similar situation as the OP (EJB's running on JBoss) and had two threads accessing the initial context without synchronization and got run-time exceptions: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [...]`. After reading this answer I synchronized access and all problems were gone. Big +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

But if I put this method inside a singleton class then can I use Context as a class variable?like in this below code method is inside a singleton `ServiceLocator` class.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class ServiceLocator {
    static volatile ServiceLocator serviceLocator = null;

    Map supportedAppServerMap = null;

    @Override
    public Object getEJB(String jndiName) {

        logger.debug("WEBSPHERE EJB Lookup : " + jndiName);
        String modifiedJndiName = "";
        Hashtable<Object, Object> properties = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, AMPPropertyUtil.getProperty("PROVIDER_URL"));
        try {
            Context context = new InitialContext(properties);
            if (null != jndiName && jndiName.indexOf(".") != -1)
                modifiedJndiName = jndiName.substring(jndiName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            else
                modifiedJndiName = jndiName;
            logger.debug("WEBSPHERE EJB Lookup Modified JNDI Name: " + modifiedJndiName);
            return context.lookup("ejblocal:" + modifiedJndiName);
        } catch (NamingException ne) {
            logger.debug("Naming Exception occurred :" + jndiName + ">>>" + ne.getMessage());
            logger.error(ne.getMessage(), ne);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        Context context = null;
        final String dsName = AMPPropertyUtil.getProperty("dsName");
        Hashtable<Object, Object> properties = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, AMPPropertyUtil.getProperty("PROVIDER_URL"));
        try {

            context = new InitialContext();
            return (DataSource) context.lookup("java:comp/env/" + dsName);

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getResources(final String jndiName) {
        Context context = null;
        Hashtable<Object, Object> properties = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, AMPPropertyUtil.getProperty("PROVIDER_URL"));
        try {
            context = new InitialContext();
            return context.lookup(jndiName);

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static ServiceLocator getInstance() {
        if (serviceLocator == null) {
            synchronized (ServiceLocator.class) {
                if (null == serviceLocator)
                    serviceLocator = new ServiceLocator();
            }
        }
        return serviceLocator;
    }

}
```