# Unable to run maven embedded tomcat for the second time

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin

I'm trying to run two sets of integration tests (two different modules) in the same build using maven tomcat plugin. The first set runs perfectly on the first module. But tomcat is unable to deploy the war for the second modukle. Instead gives following exception

```
  com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
   SEVERE: Critical error during deployment:
   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'jndi:/localhost/test-module2/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml': Illegal class loader binding
   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:760)
   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:349)
   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5014)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'jndi:/localhost/test-module2/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml': Illegal class loader binding
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:758)
   ... 11 more
   Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'jndi:/localhost/test-module2/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml': Illegal class loader binding
   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:1009)
   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:953)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:746)
   ... 11 more
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal class loader binding
   at org.apache.naming.resources.DirContextURLStreamHandler.get(DirContextURLStreamHandler.java:228)
   at org.apache.naming.resources.DirContextURLStreamHandler.openConnection(DirContextURLStreamHandler.java:90)
   at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:971)
   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.getInputStream(ConfigManager.java:1230)
   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.getDocument(ConfigManager.java:1030)
   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:1000)
   ... 14 more
```

plugin configuration in pom.xml of both the maven projects looks as below :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
        <path>/test-module2</path>
        <port>8081</port>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-tomcat</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-tomcat</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shutdown</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Does anybody have idea of why this error is occuring?

Comment: apparently gradle plugin has the same issue https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin/issues/46, https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin/issues/124, probably related to tomcat internals, as suggested by somebody in the thread. An option moving to jetty maven plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Use different names for your JNDI resource in these modules. I've hit a variation of this problem before as well. There seems to be some sort of staticity causing this. The Maven plugin executions are in the same JVM -- that of Maven. If they were executed in forked Java-s, you would most-likely not get this.

I don't think that switching to Jetty will help, although it might indeed. However, my impression is that this is somewhat more of a problem with Maven itself.

I think it may have something to do with having a static ServiceLocator somewhere (as a lot of example like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317848/is-javax-naming-initialcontext-threadsafe) show).